# Golang Regexp Named Groups and Submatches

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to match a regular expression and get the capturing group name for the match. This works when the regular expression only matches the string once, but if it matches the string more than once, `SubexpNames` doesn't return the duplicated names.

Here's an example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    re := regexp.MustCompile("(?P<first>[a-zA-Z]+) ")
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", re.SubexpNames())
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", re.FindAllStringSubmatch("Alan Turing ", -1))
}
```

The output is:

```
["" "first"]
[["Alan " "Alan"] ["Turing " "Turing"]]
```

Is it possible to get the capturing group name for each submatch?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Group names and positions are fixed:

```
re := regexp.MustCompile("(?P<first>[a-zA-Z]+) ")
groupNames := re.SubexpNames()
for matchNum, match := range re.FindAllStringSubmatch("Alan Turing ", -1) {
    for groupIdx, group := range match {
        name := groupNames[groupIdx]
        if name == "" {
            name = "*"
        }
        fmt.Printf("#%d text: '%s', group: '%s'\n", matchNum, group, name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 9):

That might be included in Go 1.14 (Q1 2020, not yet confirmed).
See "[**proposal: regexp: add `(*Regexp).SubexpIndex`** #32420](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32420)".  Update: it has been included with [commit 782fcb4](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/782fcb44b96753e6e763be91a72bcbfc3dff7ab9) in Go 1.15 (August 2020).

```
// SubexpIndex returns the index of the first subexpression with the given name,
// or else -1 if there is no subexpression with that name.
//
// Note that multiple subexpressions can be written using the same name, as in
// (?P<bob>a+)(?P<bob>b+), which declares two subexpressions named "bob".
// In this case SubexpIndex returns the index of the leftmost such subexpression
// in the regular expression.
func (*Regexp) SubexpIndex(name string) int
```

This is discussed in [CL 187919](https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/187919/).

```
re := regexp.MustCompile(`(?P<first>[a-zA-Z]+) (?P<last>[a-zA-Z]+)`)
fmt.Println(re.MatchString("Alan Turing"))
matches := re.FindStringSubmatch("Alan Turing")
lastIndex := re.SubexpIndex("last")
fmt.Printf("last => %d\n", lastIndex)
fmt.Println(matches[lastIndex])

// Output:
// true
// last => 2
// Turing
```

Comment: 2020 not 2010 (:

Comment: @Niemi Thank you. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

An example of executing ping command under Linux OS with output parsing.

```
type Result struct {
    AvgTime     time.Duration
    MaxTime     time.Duration
    MinTime     time.Duration
    MDevTime    time.Duration
    Transmitted int
    Received    int
}

func PingHostOrIp(hostOrIp string, pingCount int, timeout time.Duration) (*Result, error) {
    timeoutSec := int(timeout.Seconds())
    outBuff, err := exec.Command("ping", hostOrIp, "-q", fmt.Sprintf("-c %d", pingCount), fmt.Sprintf("-w %d", timeoutSec)).Output()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    out := string(outBuff)
    reg := regexp.MustCompile(`(\d+) packets transmitted, (\d+) received, \d+% packet loss, time .+\nrtt min/avg/max/mdev = ([\d.]+)/([\d.]+)/([\d.]+)/([\d.]+) ms`)
    subMatches := reg.FindStringSubmatch(out)
    if subMatches == nil {
        return nil, errors.New(out)
    }
    res := Result{
        AvgTime:     toDuration(subMatches[4]),
        MaxTime:     toDuration(subMatches[5]),
        MinTime:     toDuration(subMatches[3]),
        MDevTime:    toDuration(subMatches[6]),
        Transmitted: toInt(subMatches[1]),
        Received:    toInt(subMatches[2]),
    }
    return &res, nil
}

func toInt(str string) int {
    i, err := strconv.Atoi(str)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return i
}

func toDuration(str string) time.Duration {
    f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(str, 32)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    return time.Duration(100*f) * time.Microsecond
}
```