# Regex match of =~ returns wrong result when starts with .*

Tags: regex, go, gofmt

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {
    var sep = "=~"
    var filter = "exported_pod=~.*grafana.*"
    matched, _ := regexp.MatchString(sep+`\b`, filter)
    fmt.Println(matched)
}
```

In the above snippet, I'm trying to return `True` if `=~` is exactly present in the `filter` string.

Unable to understand why it's returning `false`.

It works as expected if the `filter` string is `"exported_pod=~grafana.*"` whereas if it is `"exported_pod=~.*grafana.*"`, it fails. Please help me in understanding what's wrong here.

---

The actual problem is:

**Split the string around either `=`, `=~`, `!=`, `!~`.**

In the example above, the result should be `[ "exported_pod", ".*grafana.*" ]`.
But that split should happen for *any one* of the listed separators.

Comment: If you are looking for a literal `"=~"` use strings.Contains and not a regexp.

Comment: @Volker What should be the best way to test for =, =~, !=, !~ in the strings which can regex or non-regex?

If I use string.contains("=") the problem is that it will match for string like this as well exported_pod=~.*grafana.*". (notice ~ here ).

Comment: I admit I have no idea what your actual problem is. What are "strings which can regex or non-regex". If you want to see if a string contains a `=` not followed by ~ and not preceeded by ! you can use a regexp or just code that out (which probably is much simpler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/p9U5hL/1):

`\b` matches, without consuming any characters, immediately between a character matched by `\w` (a-z) and a character not matched by `\w` (in either order).
It cannot be used to separate non words from words.

So using `\b` would not work. (irrespective of the fact regexp might not be the best fit for this case)

To simply test if the string includes `=~` (as in "[How to check if a string contains a substring in Go](https://freshman.tech/snippets/go/how-to-string-contains-substring/)")

```
fmt.Println(strings.Contains(filter, "=~")) // true
```

See this [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/RsBsvui42wP).

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    var sep = "=~"
    var filter = "exported_pod=~.*grafana.*"
    matched := strings.Contains(filter, sep)
    fmt.Println(matched)
}
```

---

If you need to test for more than one separator though, then yes, regex can help: [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/LNbdkuEBSIZ), with [regex tested here](https://regex101.com/r/JwIrys/1).

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

func main() {
    var filter = "exported_pod=~.*grafana.*"
    matched, _ := regexp.MatchString(`[^=!~](=|=~|!=|!~)[^=!~]`, filter)
    fmt.Println(matched)
}
```

Using a [regexp with a *named* capture group](https://regex101.com/r/gFSjFP/1):

```
[^=!~](?P<separator>=|=~|!=|!~)[^=!~]
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can extract that separator, using [`regexp.SubexpIndex`](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.SubexpIndex) ([Go 1.15+, Aug. 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58308223/6309)), and use it to split your original string.
See this [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/iqri4UbSnSu):

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"
import "strings"

func main() {
    var filter = "exported_pod=~.*grafana.*"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`[^=!~](?P<separator>=|=~|!=|!~)[^=!~]`)
    matches := re.FindStringSubmatch(filter)
    separator := matches[re.SubexpIndex("separator")]
    filtered := strings.Split(filter, separator)
    fmt.Println(filtered)
}
```

`filtered` is an array with parts before and after any `=~` (the separator detected by the regexp).

Comment: What should be the best way to test for =, =~, !=, !~ in the strings which can regex or non-regex?

Comment: @zubug55 I have edited the answer to include an example of an alternative approach.

Comment: I need to exact match for =, =~, !=, !~ . The problem with your approach is that "exported_pod=~.*grafana.*" will match for = as well. It should only match with =~

Comment: @zubug55 It does not match =: https://play.golang.org/p/3eziI5feXuV

Comment: package main

import (
 "fmt"
 "strings"
)

func main() {
 var sep = "="
 var filter = "exported_pod=~.*grafana.*"
 matched := strings.Contains(filter, sep)
 fmt.Println(matched)
}

This will return true.

Comment: @zubug55 I don't see any mention of =, =~, !=, !~  in your question, only =~ as a separator, with the question "why \b fails when string includes .*". I have answered that question.

Comment: @zubug55 I have edited the answer to use a regex which will match only =, =~, !=, !~

Comment: What can be the best way to split the key values after matching with the regex [^=!~](=|=~|!=|!~)[^=!~]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232884/discussion-between-vonc-and-zubug55).